# How to create a new dataframe based on value_counts of a column in another dataframe but with certain conditions on other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data-frame of tickets raised on a group of servers like this:

```
      a     b     c   Users       Problem
0  data  data  data  User A   Server Down
1  data  data  data  User B   Server Down
2  date  data  data  User C   Memory Full
3  date  data  data  User C     Swap Full
4  date  data  data  User D  Unclassified
5  date  data  data  User E  Unclassified
6  data  data  data  User B   RAM Failure
```

I need to create another dataframe like this with the data grouped by the type of tickets and the **count of tickets** raised by only two users, A and B separately and a single column with the count for other users.

Expected new Dataframe:

```
+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+
| Type Of Error | User A | User B | Other Users |
+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+
| Server Down   | 50     | 60     | 150         |
+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+
| Memory Full   | 40     | 50     | 20          |
+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+
| Swap Full     | 10     | 20     | 15          |
+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+
| Unclassified  | 10     | 20     | 50          |
+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+
|               |        |        |             |
+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

I've tried `.value_counts()` which provides total count of that type. I however need it to be based on the User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no `User A` or `User B` change users to `Other Users` by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df['Users'] = df['Users'].where(df['Users'].isin(['User A','User B']), 'Other Users')

df = pd.crosstab(df['Problem'], df['Users'])[['User A','User B','Other Users']]
print (df)
Users         User A  User B  Other Users
Problem                                  
Memory Full        0       0            1
RAM Failure        0       1            0
Server Down        1       1            0
Swap Full          0       0            1
Unclassified       0       0            2
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I didn't know about crosstab; I used this one and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pivot_table` which is great at using aggregate functions:

```
users = df.Users.copy()
users[~users.isin(['User A', 'User B'])] = 'Other Users'
df.pivot_table(index='Problem', columns=users, aggfunc='count', values='a',
               fill_value=0).reindex(['User A', 'User B', 'Other Users'], axis=1)
```

It gives:

```
Users         User A  User B  Other Users
Problem                                  
Memory Full        0       0            1
RAM Failure        0       1            0
Server Down        1       1            0
Swap Full          0       0            1
Unclassified       0       0            2
```